# Merge more than 2 dataframes together depending on column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, merge

I would like to merge a dataframe with multiple dataframes depending on a value in two columns. I know I can merge two dataframes based on an element in a column using the `merge()` function, but I dont know how to do it when there are more than 2 dataframes.

For example, take this as the primary dataframe:

```
yr.col <- c(rep("2018",3), rep("2017",4), rep("2016",5))
mnth.col <- sample.int(4,12, replace = TRUE)
lon <- c(paste(1:12,"x"))
lat <- c(paste(1:12,"y"))

df <- data.frame(yr.col,lon,lat)
```

These are the other dataframes, which have the temperature for the set of lon and lat in different years.

```
tmp_18 <- sample.int(8,12,replace = TRUE)
tmp_17 <- sample.int(8,12,replace = TRUE)
tmp_16 <- sample.int(8,12,replace = TRUE)

env_18 <- data.frame(tmp_18,lon,lat)
env_17 <- data.frame(tmp_17, lon, lat)
env_16 <- data.frame(tmp_16, lon, lat)
```

**Aim:** I want to merge `df` with either `env_18` `env_17` or `env_16` depending on `df$yr.col`

**Expected result:** A dataframe with a new column called `tmp` where the number from the correct env datasets are found

**Previously tried:**

1)

```
if (df$yr.col=="2018"){
  df.new$tmp <- merge(df,env_18, by=c("lon", "lat"))
  df.new$tmp.yr <- "2018"
}else if (df$yr.col=="2017"){
  df.new$tmp <- merge(df, env_17, by=c("lon", "lat"))
  df.new$tmp.yr <- "2017"
} else {
  df.new$tmp <- merge(df, env_16, by=c("lon", "lat"))
  df.new$tmp.yr <- "2016"}
```

produces this warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (df$yr.col == "2018") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It only takes the first dataframe `env_18` and merges that with `df`

I have also tried 2)

```
df.new <- ifelse(df$yr.col=="2018", merge(df, env_18, by=c("lon", "lat")), 
                       ifelse(df$yr.col=="2017", merge(df, env_17, by=c("lon", "lat")),
                              ifelse(df$yr.col=="2016", merge(df, env_16, by=c("lon", "lat")), "NA")))
df.new <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(df.new), nrow=length(df.new)))
```

but this does not give the desired outcome.

Is there some magic way to do this that I have not condisered or have I made an error? Perhaps a `for-loop` or `function`?
Thank you so much for your help in advance! I really appreciate it :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `purrr` for that. I could have used `inner_join`, but decided to keep `merge` as in the original post.

```
map2_dfr(list(env_16, env_17, env_18),
                2016:2018,
                function(x,y){merge(df %>% filter(yr.col == y), x, by=c("lon", "lat"))})
```

**Output**

```
lon  lat yr.col tmp_16 tmp_17 tmp_18
1  10 x 10 y   2016      1     NA     NA
2  11 x 11 y   2016      8     NA     NA
3  12 x 12 y   2016      7     NA     NA
4   8 x  8 y   2016      7     NA     NA
5   9 x  9 y   2016      2     NA     NA
6   4 x  4 y   2017     NA      5     NA
7   5 x  5 y   2017     NA      4     NA
8   6 x  6 y   2017     NA      8     NA
9   7 x  7 y   2017     NA      7     NA
10  1 x  1 y   2018     NA     NA      6
11  2 x  2 y   2018     NA     NA      2
12  3 x  3 y   2018     NA     NA      1
```

You can also create one column from `tmp`s and drop the rest:

```
df$tmp <- coalesce(df$tmp_16, df$tmp_17, df$tmp_18)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it works! I just had to make sure I called the `map2_dfr` into a new dataframe to then `coalesce()` on.
You mention `inner_join`, out of interest how would I do it that way?

Comment: Also please may I confrim what the `filter(yr.col==y)` does in the function bit? Thank you again

Comment: @EveTC `inner_join` does the same as `merge`, just a function from a different package (`dplyr`). `filter (yr.col==y)` subsets the original data frame for a given `y` - in other words, filters it based on the year